# How can I use AutoHotKey to get the text in a control?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using a bookkeeping system that had a minor crash. Now I'm cleaning up, and using AutoHotKey 1.1.26.00 to do it. The process involves going through a long listbox of items, and for each item I have to right-click through a series of windows with both the keyboard and mouse. It's all working...mostly.

Before the last window closes, a dialog box pops up, on which a "No" button is clicked. I've added code to do this. But about 5% of the time the dialog has a different message, and this blocks the AHK script from continuing. I'm trying to get the text of the message, but I cannot determine how. The name of the control is `Static2`, but none of the AHK functions seem able to access the text.

I used the following script that I found in the AHK help to determine the name of the control:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, WatchCursor, 100
Return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, X, Y, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, ahk_id %id%`nahk_class %class%`n%title%`nControl: %control%`nXpos = %X%`nYpos = %Y%
Return
```

The script returns the following:

```
ahk_id 0x170586
ahk_class #32770
Control: Static2
```

Can I use this information to get the text in `Static2`..? If so, how..?

Unfortunately the dialog does not have a window title of its own. I attempted to get the title, but found it matches the parent window. So...I don't know what to try next.

The full code of my AHK script is below and there's a screenshot at the end.

The dialog text which I need to check is usually `Do you want to edit the accounting information at this time?`, but as stated, this is occasionally different, and I need to add more code to process that. This happens in the last section of the script:

```
;Written for AutoHotkey v1.1.26.00

#NoEnv                          ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn                           ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input                  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%     ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

DelayMenu1  := 500  ; Wait for the menu to open.
DelayMenu2  := 75   ; As the selection moves down each item in the menu.
DelayMenu3  := 200  ; So the last item selected can be seen.
DelayWin1   := 200  ; After each window opens, a little time for the controls to populate.
ItemPosX    := 450  ; X-position of the first item in the list.
ItemPosY    := 104  ; Y-position of the first item in the list.
ItemAddY    := 14   ; Y-distance between each item.

;Activate the main window.
WinActivate, Dispatcher - Roadnet Transportation Suite
Sleep 500

;Get input from the user.
InputBox, C, Number of rows, How many rows?
If ErrorLevel
    {
    } Else {

        ; #################### BEGIN LOOP ####################

        Loop, %C%
            {
            
                ;Wait for the main window.
                WinWaitActive, Dispatcher - Roadnet Transportation Suite, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Main window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ; #################### START ####################
            
                ;Right-click the item and wait for the menu to open.
                MouseMove, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%
                Click, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%, Right
                Sleep %DelayMenu1%
                
                ;Press the down key to "Start".
                Loop, 8
                    {
                        SendInput, {DOWN}
                        Sleep %DelayMenu2%
                    }
                Sleep %DelayMenu3%
                SendInput, {ENTER}

                ;Wait for "Start Route" window.
                WinWaitActive, Start Route, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Start Route window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ;Use the Save keystroke. On other windows this does not work; mouse must be used.
                SendInput ^s
                Sleep 250

                ;Wait for the main window.
                WinWaitActive, Dispatcher - Roadnet Transportation Suite, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Main window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ; #################### STOP COMPLETE ####################

                ;Right-click the item and wait for the menu to open.
                MouseMove, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%
                Click, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%, Right
                Sleep %DelayMenu1%
                
                ;Press the down key to "Stop Complete".
                Loop, 2
                    {
                        SendInput, {DOWN}
                        Sleep %DelayMenu2%
                    }
                Sleep %DelayMenu3%
                SendInput, {ENTER}

                ;Wait for "Stop Complete" window.
                WinWaitActive, Stop Complete, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Stop Complete window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ;Click the "As Projected" button. The keyboard shortcut does not work; mouse must be used.
                Click, 120, 36
                Sleep 250

                ;Click the "Save" button. The keyboard shortcut does not work; mouse must be used.
                ;Note: At this point the button sticks in, and the mouse becomes an hourglass.
                Click, 24, 36
                Sleep 250

                ;Wait for the main window.
                WinWaitActive, Dispatcher - Roadnet Transportation Suite, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Main window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ; #################### COMPLETE ####################

                ;Right-click the item and wait for the menu to open.
                MouseMove, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%
                Click, %ItemPosX%, %ItemPosY%, Right
                Sleep %DelayMenu1%
                
                ;Press the down key to "Complete".
                Loop, 9
                    {
                        SendInput, {DOWN}
                        Sleep %DelayMenu2%
                    }
                Sleep %DelayMenu3%
                SendInput, {ENTER}

                ;Wait for "Complete Route" window.
                WinWaitActive, Complete Route, , 3
                If ErrorLevel
                    {
                        MsgBox, Complete Route window is not visible.
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep %DelayWin1%

                ;For troubleshooting.
                ;MsgBox, %ClassID%`n%ControlName%
                ;WinGet, active_id, ID, A

                ;Click the "Save" button. The keyboard shortcut does not work; mouse must be used.
                Click, 24, 36
                Sleep 250
                
                ;Check if the accounting information dialog appeared.
                ;The message is usually: "Do you want to edit the accounting information at this time?"
                DialogAppeared := 0
                Loop, 10 ;Check 10 times.
                    {
                        ;Check for 
                        MouseMove, 340, 120
                        MouseGetPos, , , ClassID, ControlName
                        If (ControlName = "Button2") ;Use this button to check for the popup dialog.
                            {
                                DialogAppeared := 1
                                Break
                            } Else {
                                Sleep 250
                            }
                    }
                If (DialogAppeared = 1)
                    {
                        ;Click the "No" button. There is no keyboard shortcut; mouse must be used.
                        MouseMove, 340, 120
                        Click, 340, 120
                    } Else {
                        MsgBox, "The accounting information dialog could not be handled."
                        Exit
                    }
                Sleep 250

                ; #################### DONE ####################

                ;Increment the row-Y value before repeating the loop.
                ItemPosY := ItemPosY + ItemAddY
            }
    }

MsgBox, Done.
Exit
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the program and/or the popup? And to *"none of the AHK functions seem able to access the text"*, which methods did you try so far?

Comment: Ok I added a screenshot to the end of my OP. It's not the original dialog; I couldn't reproduce the original, but it's the exact same presentation. There's the main window in the background, then a pop-up window, and then the dialog. I tried WinGetText and ControlGetText, but neither gave any output. I think it's because the dialog has no title that it can detect, but I'm not sure. I don't have the code any more because I already edited it out and went for a polling loop that watches for the "No" button on the dialog (the dialog in the screenshot only has an Ok button).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the answer (yet at least), but can't really post this in the comments.
So from taking a quick look at a image, I'd guess that you should be able to retrieve the control's contents with normal WinAPI methods (it doesn't seem to be some app that would be built in some special framework, though it's super old, so I could be wrong. Not too familiar with super old ones)

Maybe something went wrong when you tried `ControlGetText`.
What results do you get with this?

```
F1::
    MouseGetPos, , , window, ctrl
    ControlGetText, text, % ctrl, % "ahk_id " window
    MsgBox, % "Window's HWND: " window "`nControl's name: " Ctrl "`nControl's text: " text
return
```

To use it, just put your mouse over the control from which you want to retrieve text and press F1.
Try it maybe in like notepad first and you should see how it works.

If that doesn't do the trick, I'd recommend downloading "Winspector Spy" and trying to take a deeper look at the window's and controls. Manually see if the text you're looking for is found somewhere there.